# How do you see the availabilty zones of an Azure Data Explorer Cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

It's mentioned in the Microsoft Docs that an Azure Data Explorer Cluster can be created with availablity zones, but not edited after creation.

We have an existing cluster where I am trying to see if it was created with availablity zones selected, however I cannot work out where to find this within the Azure Portal. Maybe a very dumb question but where can I go to check if my instance has availability zones set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the availability zones of a particular Adx cluster either from portal, PowerShell cmdlets or through by using Azure management Rest API's.

Using [Get-AzKustoCluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.kusto/get-azkustocluster?view=azps-9.1.0) cmdlet to list the properties of the cluster.

```
 get-azkustocluster -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <ClusterName> | select -Property Name,Zone
```

[Cluster-Get REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurerekusto/clusters/get?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) to get the information about cluster and it's properties.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/{clusterName}?api-version=2022-07-07
```

From **Azure Portal** in the overview page under instance count as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you. As I expected I was being dumb. I've never had to expand the main details on the overview page so completely missed the "Show more" label. For anoyone else reading, it turns out the availabilty zones detail is the only bit of information hidden until you click that.